# jquery ui-autocomplete is not showing the dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

In search box the ui-autocomplete dropdown has stopped working all of sudden. Server is returning the queryset but jquery is not executing `response` section.

My html form:

```
      <form class="d-flex ps-0 pe-0" method="get" action="{% url 'search-name' %}">
        <input class="form-control reduceboxsize" value="{{ query }}" name="q" type="search" placeholder="Search" id="snametag" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" name="st" value="{{st.url}}" type="submit">&#x1F50D;</button>
      </form>
    <button class="navbar-toggler btn btn-sm ps-0" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"  data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
```

jquery function:

```
function enableautocomplete() {
    ///// search ////// http://jsbin.com/xavatajiku/edit?js,output
    if (document.getElementById('snametag')) {
    $('#snametag').autocomplete({
            minLength: 4,
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/sm/shpd/",
                    data: { searchText: request.term, maxResults: 10, shopId: 'organic'},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log('return', data);
                        //response(data);
                        response($.map(data.results, function (item) {
                            console.log('data.results', data.results);

                            return {
                                product_name: item.name,
                                url: item.url,
                                pfimage_thumb: item.photo,
                                ourprice: 6,
                            };
                        }));
                    }
                })
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
             return false;
                },
            close : function (event, ui) {
                    return false;
                }
        }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        console.log(item.url);
            var inner_html = '<div class="row searching-box"><div class="image col-sm-1"><a href="/market/1/'+item.url+'"><img src="' + item.pfimage_thumb + '" height="42" width="42"></a></div><div class="description col-sm-8"><a class="link-decoration-none" href="/market/1/'+item.url+'">' + item.product_name + '<button type="submit" onclick="create_post('+myVars.shId+','+item.products+',\''+item.product_name+'\','+item.ourprice+')" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">View</button></a></div></div>';
            return $("<li class='list-group-item'></li>")
                    .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
                    .append(inner_html)
                    .appendTo(ul);
        };
    }
    };
```

For example: if we type "palm" in tharuvi.com search box it will show a dropdown of products matching the query (ui-autocomplete). Now the products are printed in Console log but dropdown portion is not working.

Any valuable suggestions would help.

Comment: data.results is a problem. use data only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) below lines of code is unnecessay so remove them (take care of removing corresponding closing brackets too):

```
function enableautocomplete() {
///// search ////// http://jsbin.com/xavatajiku/edit?js,output
if (document.getElementById('snametag')) {
```

b) change `data.results` to `data`

I have directly used the below code on your site and it worked:

```
$('#snametag').autocomplete({
        minLength: 4,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/sm/shpd/",
                data: { searchText: request.term, maxResults: 10, shopId: 'organic'},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('return', data);
                    //response(data);
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            product_name: item.name,
                            url: item.url,
                            pfimage_thumb: item.photo,
                            ourprice: 6,
                        };
                    }));
                }
            })
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
         return false;
            },
        close : function (event, ui) {
                return false;
            }
    }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        var inner_html = '<div class="row searching-box"><div class="image col-sm-1"><a href="/market/1/'+item.url+'"><img src="' + item.pfimage_thumb + '" height="42" width="42"></a></div><div class="description col-sm-8"><a class="link-decoration-none" href="/market/1/'+item.url+'">' + item.product_name + '<button type="submit" onclick="create_post('+myVars.shId+','+item.products+',\''+item.product_name+'\','+item.ourprice+')" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">View</button></a></div></div>';
        return $("<li class='list-group-item'></li>")
                .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
                .append(inner_html)
                .appendTo(ul);
    };
```

The result on your website: https://prnt.sc/eoLiVv6iGAWO

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem is fixed, it just works fine now. Thank you again.